# variables as the target key of an immutability-helper merge

Tags: reactjs, immutability

Given an `immutability-helper` stanza like:

```
new_state = update(this.state, {$merge: {
  name: event.target.value
}});
```

Is there any way to replace the 'name' key above with an argument/variable? I'd like to make this type of handler more generic. As in send an arg to the function containing this stanza which tells update what to merge, similar to (doesn't work, tries to create key 'arg'):

```
handleChange = (arg, event) => {
  new_state = update(this.state, {$merge: {
      arg: event.target.checked
    }})
  // setState(), etc.
}
```

I can't figure out the secret sauce to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to update a dynamic key, you need to add them within `[]` like

```
handleChange = (arg, event) => {
  new_state = update(this.state, {$merge: {
      [arg]: event.target.checked
    }})
  // setState(), etc.
}
```

You can find the documentation **[here](http://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper#computed-property-nam%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bes)**

Comment: Really? I figured it would be that easy, somehow. Where is this documented? I don't see anything about it on the immutability-helper npm page... Can't try it out from here - will try tonight and get back - thanks!

Comment: thanks, works like a charm. Sorry for the delayed reply, I was away from this for a few days... Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: I will try to find a documentation for this add it to the answer

Comment: It's documented here:
https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper#computed-property-names

Comment: @lakim, Thanks for adding the documentation link